# Recursive CTE with non-numeric hierarchy data

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a (simplified) table:

```
OrgName  |  Hierarchy
---------|------------
Org1     | A
Org2     | AA
Org3     | AB
Org4     | ABA
```

An organization is a child of another organization if:

1. The child's length is 1 greater than the parent
2. The parent's Hierarchy code exactly matches the first `LEN(Parent.Hierarchy)` of the child's code

So in my table:

1. Org2 and Org3 are children to Org1
2. Org4 is a child of Org3 and a grandchild to Org1

My question is how do I write a recursive hierarchy to find all descendants of a particular organization? All of the CTE examples I've read have numeric conditions of the join (like `Employee.ManagerID = CTE.EmpID`). Here's what I have so far:

```
DELCARE @search VARCHARE = 'A'
WITH Org_cte (OrgName, HLevel, RecursionLevel)
AS
  (SELECT o.OrgName, o.Hierarchy, 0 as RecursionLevel
   FROM OrgTable o
   WHERE o.Hierarchy = @search
   UNION ALL
   SELECT o.OrgName, o.Hierarchy, RecursionLevel + 1
   FROM OrgTable o
   INNER JOIN Org_cte
   ON ???)

SELECT OrgName, HLevel, Recursion FROM Org_cte
```

I'm fairly new to CTE, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

This should do it. I overlooked that you start with recursion level 0 and that the same level needs to be excluded:

```
WITH org_cte (OrgName, HLevel, RecursionLevel)
AS
(
   SELECT o.OrgName, o.Hierarchy, 1 as RecursionLevel
   FROM OrgTable o
   WHERE o.Hierarchy = 'A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT o.OrgName, o.Hierarchy, RecursionLevel + 1
   FROM OrgTable o
   JOIN Org_cte
     ON substring(o.hierarchy, 1, org_cte.recursionLevel) = org_cte.hlevel 
        AND o.hierarchy <> org_cte.hlevel
)
SELECT OrgName, HLevel, RecursionLevel 
FROM Org_cte
```

Comment: This only returns the 'anchor' row, I think you're onto something though

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it lead me to the answer:
    INNER JOIN Org_cte
      ON substring(o.hierarchy, 1, org_cte.recursionLevel) = org_cte.hlevel
      AND LEN(o.hierarchy) = LEN(org_cte.HLevel) + 1

I also had to change the anchor's RecursionLevel to 1 from 0

Comment: @SupremeDud: see my edit. We came up with nearly the same thing ;)